# How to check if product exists or not laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this functionality where user can add product to cart. e.g so user can add one product in cart after sometime the product gets deleted by the seller but still it is in the users cart, so if he checks out one product which has been deleted it will redirect him back to cart saying the product was deleted(one product works fine) but if he has two products in the cart one has been deleted and the other has not, and tries to check out he gets an error `trying to get property of non object`. So I'm looping over the product ids and checking if the product still exists in the database, but if that check fails for one, but not another I want the user to be redirected to the cart, so it should only checkout if no product fails. How can I do this ?

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach (session('cart') as $productId => $item) ;
    $product = product::find($productId);
    if (!$product) {
        return redirect()->route('cart')
        }
    //Insert into orders table
    $order = Order::create([
        'shipping_email' => $request->email,
        'shipping_name' => $request->name,
        'shipping_city' => $request->city,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,

    ]);

    //Insert into order product table
    if ($order) {
        $total = 0;
        foreach (session('cart') as $productId => $item) {
            if (empty($item)) {
                continue;
            }
            $product = product::find($productId);
            OrderProduct::create([
                'order_id' => $order->id ?? null,
                'product_id' => $productId,
                // $products=DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->get();
                'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
                'Subtotal' => $item['price'] * $item['quantity'],
                'total' => $total += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'],
                'price' => $product->price,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'info' => $product->info,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you tried to do with `foreach (session('cart') as $productId => $item) ;`?

Comment: `foreach (session('cart') as $productId => $item)` is the user session(cart) @RomanBobrik

Comment: ok, but your loop ends on the same string, cause you added `;`, is it misspell?

Comment: which line? I think is not a misspell @RomanBobrik

Comment: third line. and where are you getting error exactly?

Comment: Oh yeah it is a misspell, I'm getting an error from this line `'price' => $product->price,` which is `trying to get property of non object` @RomanBobrik

Comment: your product model named with lowercase? `$product = product::find($productId);`
seems like you getting null here

Comment: I get null if one of the product was deleted @RomanBobrik

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have model `Product`, but you are trying to find `product`.

So, try:

`$product = Product::find($productId);`

instead of

`$product = product::find($productId);`

Comment: Even if I changed the model to this `$product = Product::find($productId);` still I get errors but I just found the problem and it works, so I tried to remove `;` in the third line and put `{}` and it works, so thanks .@Roman Bobrik

Answer (score 0):

You can try `firstOrCreate()` function if product exists no thing will di and if product does not exists , this will create anew product to cart

Comment: You can give a little more detail about your proposal so that it is more helpful for more people